# How to use multi values : key is in integer value is in String

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Having only one key for multi values. how to display all the values with single key in loop or in html

```
Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();

for (int k = 0; k < dateDayTypeList.size(); k++) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(dateDayTypeList.get(k)[0].toString()),dateDayTypeList.get(k)[1].toString());
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: we tried to split it in a loop but it pops a not proper code. how to get those multiple values in loop or in anyways

Comment: @Amya can you explain more about it?

Comment: You are trying to display but why you need to add to map?

Answer (score 1):

Get the map of key and value using `entrySet();` and iterate through the loop .

```
    Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
    map.put(1,new String[]{"x","Y"});
    map.put(2,new String[]{"AB","CD"});
    map.put(3,new String[]{"ee","SS"});

    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String[]> entry:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.print(entry.getKey()+":");
        for (String value :entry.getValue()){
            System.out.print(value);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Output

```
1:xY
2:ABCD
3:eeSS
```